# Display results on combobox by selecting a value on another combobox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpmyadmin

I have a problem in my project. I have these categories:

```
Football
Basketball
Tennis
```

and these sub categories:

```
super league A
super league B
euroleague
Serie A
```

I have the categories and sub categories in my phpMyAdmin DB.
I have this code now, that I display these two, in two different comboboxes, via queries from DB:

```
<?php
$category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM katigories ORDER BY id_katigoria");
echo "<select name='katigoria'>";
echo "<option selected='selected' value='0'> Επιλογή κατηγορίας! </option>";
while($values = mysql_fetch_assoc($category))
{
    echo "<option value='$values[id_katigoria]'>".$values['katigoria']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

and

```
<?php
$category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upokatigories ORDER BY id_upokatigoria");
echo "<select name='upokatigoria'>";
echo "<option selected='selected' value='0'> Επιλογή υποκατηγορίας! </option>";
while($values = mysql_fetch_assoc($category))
{
    echo "<option value='$values[id_upokatigoria]'>".$values['katigoria']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

so far so good. But now my problem is that I want to select from the first one Basketball, and I want to see ONLY the euroleague to the second combobox.

I don't know much about JS or jQuery, but I believe between two of them is the answer I am looking for. Am I right?

Please any ideas, to continue, or any suggestions, about what to read and where to look?

P.S. I found something similar here, but it was for C# or/and python..so, I hope I am not repeating any other questions

Comment: The Answer is Following AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You need some jQuery that makes an ajax call to the server to bring back the new dropdown list.  See here: http://www.codingcereal.com/2009/09/autopopulate-select-dropdown-box-using-jquery/

Comment: unfortunately, it is difficult for me :(  I can not complete this tutorial..Also, I found these plug-ins. I post the link here, for someone maybe will be helpful and interesting

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Any other idea, how to do it?

Comment: Try this one.  The more you read the easier it will become.  http://www.x-developer.com/php-scripts/loading-drop-downs-with-ajax-php-and-fetching-values-from-database-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: It might be worth doing something simpler first like this. This one does not use jQuery and only displays a row of data on selecting from the dropdown.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp